# How to print every 17th number, 0-200, skipping even numbers?

Tags: bash, loops, shell, for-loop, step-through

I need to write a Bash/Shell code that prints every 17th number from 0 to 200, skipping all even numbers.

This is the code I have right now (I know it doesn't work as intended):

```
for i in {0..200..17}
do
if [ $(($i % 2)) ]
then
  echo -n "${i}, "
fi
done;
```

I need to print an output that looks like this:

`17, 51, 85, 119, 153, 187`

I have the part where it steps through every 17th number, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to skip every even number and every guide I've read through online doesn't help. Appreciation in advance!

Comment: If you use `{17..200..34}` as your brace expansion then you get the list that you want without doing any arithmetic in the loop.

Comment: @pjh Yes, something like `printf -v line '%d, ' {17..200..34};echo ${line%, }`

Comment: Or even (only odd): `( arr=({0..200..17});arr=(${arr[*]/%*+([02468])});IFS=,;echo "${arr[*]}" )`

Comment: so what you really want is every 34th number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `[ $(($i % 2)) ]` into `(( i % 2 ))` so you're simply doing an arithmetic operation and testing the **result** (success=0/fail=non-zero exit status) rather than an arithmetic operation and then testing the **output** of that operation.

Output:

```
$ echo $((27 % 2))
1

$ echo $((26 % 2))
0
```

Exit status:

```
$ ((27 % 2)); echo $?
0

$ ((26 % 2)); echo $?
1
```

Answer (score 2):

What I would do:

```
for i in {0..200..17}; do ((i % 2)) && echo "$i"; done
```

```
17
51
85
119
153
18
```

---

`((...))` and `$((...))` are arithmetic commands, which returns an exit status of 0 if the expression is nonzero, or 1 if the expression is zero. Also used as a synonym for "let", if side effects (assignments) are needed.

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression